# Adding a record to a sql query

Tags: sql, db2

All,

I am a novice to SQL and have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out on my own without success. I need to add a record to my query results with some literal text and a record count and a count of distinct locations. I have two queries, shown below, and each give me the result I want but I have been unable to combine them using union all, honestly I don't know if that is even the correct approach.

First query:

```
SELECT HHIITMN AS "Product Number", SUBSTR(HHIDTES,5,2) || SUBSTR(HHIDTES,7,2) ||
    SUBSTR(HHIDTES,1,4) AS "Transaction Date",

    CASE HHIBCCD WHEN 'Y' THEN CAST(ROUND(((HHIQYSA/HHIPCKI)*100),0) AS DECIMAL(12,0))
        ELSE CAST(ROUND((HHIQYSA*100),0) AS DECIMAL(12,0))
        END AS "Quantity",

    CAST(ROUND((HHIPRCN*100),0) AS DECIMAL(12,0)) AS "Unit Price",

    CAST(ROUND((HHIQYSA*100),0) * ROUND((HHIPRCN*100),0) AS DECIMAL(12,0)) AS "Total 
Price",

    '1' AS "Distributor Number", HHICUSN AS "Operator Number",

    CASE HHICWCD WHEN 'Y' THEN CAST(ROUND((HHIEXCW*100),0) AS DECIMAL(15,0)) ELSE 0 END 
        AS "Weight Shipped",

    CASE
        WHEN HHICWCD = 'Y' THEN 'LB'
        WHEN HHIBCCD = 'Y' THEN 'EA'
        ELSE 'CS'
        END AS "Item Unit Of Measure"

FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHIORDDP --Order Detail History
WHERE HHICMPN = '  1' 

    -- AND HHIDTES = DEC(DATE(DAYS(CURRENT_DATE)-1)) -- Production

    AND HHIINVN IN ('3610036', '3610037', '3610038') -- Test

ORDER BY HHIDTES, HHICUSN, HHIITMN
```

It produces results like this:

| Product Number | Transaction Date | Quantity | Unit Price | Total Price | Distributor Number | Operator Number | Weight Shipped | Item Unit Of Measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18655 | 7182022 | 500 | 6259 | 3129500 | 1 | 100302 | 0 | CS |
| 20141 | 7182022 | 100 | 3213 | 321300 | 1 | 100302 | 0 | CS |

The second query to create the trailing record is as follows:

```sql
SELECT '1234', SUBSTR(DEC(DATE(CURRENT_DATE)),5,2) || 
    SUBSTR(DEC(DATE(CURRENT_DATE)),7,2) || 
    SUBSTR(DEC(DATE(CURRENT_DATE)),1,4),
    'RECORDCOUNT=', COUNT(*), 'HOUSECOUNT=', COUNT(DISTINCT HHICUSN), 'v2.0'

FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHIORDDP 
WHERE HHICMPN = '  1' 
    AND HHIINVN IN ('3610036', '3610037', '3610038')
```

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8252022 | RECORDCOUNT= | 74 | HOUSECOUNT= | 3 | v2.0 |  |  |

How can I combine these results?
Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Not just the number of columns needs to match, but also the **data types**. You cannot use `RECORDCOUNT=` for column 3, since it doesn't match up with a numeric `Quantity` column. Same for `HOUSECOUNT=` in column 5, since the string won't fit in a price column, and `v2.0` in column 7, since that version string won't fit with the Weight Shipped numeric values. But, as the answer indicates, this is a mistake to attempt in the first place. Finally, you're formatting the dates the hard (and error-prone) way. Look at `To_CHAR()`/`VARCHAR_FORMAT()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that for my date fields. How would you recommend I add this record to my query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `UNION ALL`, both queries' result must have the same structure.
they should return matching number of columns, and matching column types (in the same column order).

Generally, every sql query result have a structure and you can't combine unrelated queries to the same result.

In tools like Excel, (or BI tools, but that may be and overkill) you can set cells or cell groups to hold results from different queries and maybe arrange them in the way you want it displayed.

Comment: Agreed. In summary: it's a mistake to try to include the summary data as a result row in the first place. Let your client platform or reporting tool handle it.

Comment: Is there a way to add a trailing record like this to my query results?

Comment: @DanB. The normal practice is configuring your client code or reporting tool to get this info from the metadata of the result set or run an additional query (you can put two SQL into the same command object in client code to get two result sets!). What you are asking to do is not good practice.